# Is there a way to swap shutter speed and aperture dials functionality for Canon EOS cameras?

Tags: canon, camera-settings, camera-controls

Is there a way to set exposure compensation with the top dial on Canon EOS (5D Mk ii) in Tv mode? It seems to me more handy that in Tv mode when I have set shutter speed I need more often to adjust exposure compensation and it's easily done with one hand using the top dial instead of the rear one used in other mode to set aperture.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to do what you want.

You can swap which direction of each dial/wheel increases/decreases exposure. You can swap which dial/wheel controls Av and which controls Tv in **Manual** exposure mode. But you can't assign exposure compensation to anything but the rear wheel.